# fields_for polymorphic join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm creating a custom CMS with a Page model and a Blocks system for the content of those pages. A simplified view of the data model is:

```
Page
has_many :blocks
has_many :text_blocks, through: :blocks, source: :blockable, source_type: "TextBlock", dependent: :destroy
has_many :image_blocks, through: :blocks, source: :blockable, source_type: "ImageBlock", dependent: :destroy

Block
belongs_to :page
belongs_to :blockable, polymorphic: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :blockable

TextBlock
has_one :block, as: :blockable

ImageBlock
belongs_to :image
has_one :block, as: :blockable
```

In the controller, I'm setting up the @block with a blockable of the appropriate type based on a param. I'm trying to create a form with a structure similar to this:

```
=form_for @block do |f|
    <<<Block Attributes Here>>>

    =f.fields_for :blockable do |bf|
        = render bf.object.class_name.downcase.underscore + "_fields"
```

This renders the form correctly, but when I save the block, it only sets the blockable_type field, and does not save the blockable or set the blockable_id. The only way I've found to get it working is to manually create the blockable in the create action. This seems like it shouldn't be necessary. My app has a similar structure for navigation lists as well, so I'd really like to find out why this isn't working without what feels like "hackish" code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This might not work, but have you tried outputting the fields directly:

```
  =f.fields_for :blockable do |bf|
     = f.text_field :blockable
```

I looked at other SO answers, and seems if it's polymorphic - Rails should do the work for you